# Rspec and Capybara uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara, bdd

I am using Rspec 3.2 and Capybara 2.4 in a non RoR project. I am trying to test with feature mode provided by Capybara gem.

```
$ cat .rspec                                                                                    
--color
--require spec_helper

$ cat spec/features/test_spec.rb                                                                
feature 'login' do
    username ="rspec#{Time.now.to_i}"
    valid_email = "#{username}@gmail.com"

    scenario 'with valid email' do
      sign_up_with  valid_email, 'pwd', 'pwd', username
      expect(page).to have_content('LOGOUT')
    end
  end

$ cat spec/support/session_helper.rb                                                            
module SessionHelper
  def sign_up_with(email, password, confirm_password, username)
      visit '/signup'
      fill_in 'email', with: email
      fill_in 'password', with: password
      fill_in 'passconf', with: confirm_password
      fill_in 'username', with: username
      click_button 'submit'
  end
end

$ cat spec/spec_helper.rb                                                                       
require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include SessionHelper, type: :feature
  ...
end
```

This is a non RoR project, when I run the test I have this error:

```
$ rspec                                                                                         
spec/spec_helper.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant SessionHelper (NameError)
```

In online documentation there are many examples, I have structured my files like the examples but it not works.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this in all of my projects is like this:

Require all the support files:

In **spec_helper.rb**

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

And then your **spec/support/session_helper.rb** should look like this:

```
module SessionHelper
  def sign_up_with(email, password, confirm_password, username)
      visit '/signup'
      fill_in 'email', with: email
      fill_in 'password', with: password
      fill_in 'passconf', with: confirm_password
      fill_in 'username', with: username
      click_button 'submit'
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove the equivalent line from spec_helper.rb
  config.include(SessionHelper)
end
```